# How to fill data to Facebook textbox using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to create an Chrome extension which can help me:

- Fill some data(text/link) to textbox of Facebook Group then click to Post( I mean: Post status Facebook using exention not using my hand)
- It's not textarea so i can't use: $('textarea').... to set value of that textbox.

Example:

[image]

Please help me! Thank so much

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I don't understand your question. My question is "How to fill data to textbox on Facebook Group using jquery"( I am writing an Chrome Extension).
i Try below code but it's working:

$('._1p1t').addClass('_1p1u');
       $('._1p1t').remove();
        $('br[data-text="true"]').remove();
        $('span[data-text="true"]').text("some content");

Comment: Why? Why would you prefill the message?